# Simulating data in R with multiple probability distributions

Tags: r, simulation, probability, resampling, replicate

I am trying to simulate data via bootstrapping to create confidence bands for my real data with a funnel plot. I am building on the strategy of the accepted answer  [to a previous question](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/175834/detecting-outliers-along-the-distribution-in-a-scatter-plot). Instead of using a single probability distribution for simulating my data I want to modify it to use different probability distributions depending on the part of the data being simulated.

I greatly appreciate anyone who can help answer the question or help me phrase the question more clearly.

My problem is writing the appropriate R code to do a more complicated form of data simulation.

The current code is:

```
n <- 1e4
set.seed(42)
sims <- sapply(1:80, 
               function(k) 
                 rowSums(
                   replicate(k, sample((1:7)/10, n, TRUE, ps))) / k)
```

This code simulates data where each data point has a value which is the mean of between `1:80` observations.
For example, when the values of the data points are the mean of 10 observations (`k`=10) it randomly samples 10 values (which can be either 0.1,0.2,0.3, 0.4, 0.5,0.6 or 0.7) based on a probability distribution `ps`, which gives the probability of each value (based on the entire empirical distribution).

ps looks like this:

```
ps <- prop.table(table((DF$mean_score)[DF$total_number_snps == 1]))
#        0.1         0.2         0.3         0.4         0.5         0.6         0.7 
#0.582089552 0.194029851 0.124378109 0.059701493 0.029850746 0.004975124 0.004975124
```

eg probability that the value of an observation is `0.1` is `0.582089552`.

Now instead of using one frequency distribution for all simulations I would like to use different frequency distributions conditionally depending on the number of observations underlying each datapoint.

I made a table, `cond_probs`, that has a row for each of my real data points. There is a column with the `total` number of observations and a column giving the frequency of each of the values for each observation.

Example of the cond_probs table:

```
gene_name   0.1 0.2 0.3 0.4 0.5 0.6 0.7 0.8 0.9 1.0 total
A1  0.664   0.319   0.018   0.000   0.000   0.000   0.000   0.000   0.000   113.000
A2  0.000   1.000   0.000   0.000   0.000   0.000   0.000   0.000   0.000   1.000
```

So for the data point `A2`, there is only `1` observation, which has a value of `0.1`. Therefore the frequency of the `0.1` observations is `1`. For `A1`, there are `113` observations and the majority of those (`0.664`) have the value `0.1`. The idea is that `cond_probs` is like `ps`, but `cond_probs` has a probability distribution for each data point rather than one for all the data.

I would like to modify the above code so that the sampling is modified to use `cond_probs` instead of `ps` for the frequency distribution. And to use the number of observations, `k` , as a criteria when choosing which row in `cond_probs` to sample from. So it would work like this:

For data points with `k` number of observations:

look in the `cond_probs` table and randomly select a row where the `total` number of observations is similar in size to k: `0.9k-1.1k`. If no such rows exist, continue.

Once a datapoint is selected, use the probability distribution from that line in `cond_probs` just like `ps` is used in the original code, to randomly sample `k` number of observations and output the mean of these observations.

For each of the `n` iterations of `replicate`, randomly sample with replacement a new data point from `cond_probs`, out of all rows where the value of `total` is similar to the current value of `k` ( `0.9k-1.1k`).

The idea is that for this dataset one should condition which probability distribution to use based on the number of observations underlying a data point. This is because in this dataset the probability of an observation is influenced by the number of observations (genes with more SNPs tend to have a lower score per observation due to genetic linkage and background selection).

UPDATE USING ANSWER BELOW:

I tried using the answer below and it works for the simulated cond_probs data in the example but not for my real cond_probs file. 
I imported and converted my cond_probs file to a matrix with

```
cond_probs <- read.table("cond_probs.txt", header = TRUE, check.names = FALSE)
cond_probs <- as.matrix(cond_probs)
```

and the first example ten rows (out of ~20,000 rows) looks like this:

```
>cond_probs
       total   0.1   0.2   0.3   0.4   0.5   0.6   0.7   0.8   0.9   1.0
[1,]     109 0.404 0.174 0.064 0.183 0.165 0.009 0.000 0.000 0.000 0.000
[2,]     181 0.564 0.221 0.144 0.066 0.006 0.000 0.000 0.000 0.000 0.000
[3,]     289 0.388 0.166 0.118 0.114 0.090 0.093 0.028 0.003 0.000 0.000
[4,]     388 0.601 0.214 0.139 0.039 0.008 0.000 0.000 0.000 0.000 0.000
[5,]     133 0.541 0.331 0.113 0.000 0.008 0.008 0.000 0.000 0.000 0.000
[6,]     221 0.525 0.376 0.068 0.032 0.000 0.000 0.000 0.000 0.000 0.000
[7,]     147 0.517 0.190 0.150 0.054 0.034 0.048 0.007 0.000 0.000 0.000
[8,]     107 0.458 0.196 0.252 0.084 0.009 0.000 0.000 0.000 0.000 0.000
[9,]      13 0.846 0.154 0.000 0.000 0.000 0.000 0.000 0.000 0.000 0.000
```

If I run:

```
sampleSize <- 20
set.seed(42)
#replace 1:80 with 1: max number of SNPs in gene in dataset
sims_test <- sapply( 1:50, simulateData, sampleSize )
```

and look at the means from the sampling with x number of observations I only get a single result, when there should be 20.

for example:

```
> sims_test[[31]]
[1] 0.1
```

And `sims_test` is not ordered in the same way as `sims`:

```
>sims_test
   [,1] [,2]      [,3]  [,4] [,5]      [,6]      [,7]   [,8]      [,9]
 [1,]  0.1  0.1 0.1666667 0.200 0.14 0.2666667 0.2000000 0.2375 0.1888889
 [2,]  0.1  0.1 0.1333333 0.200 0.14 0.2333333 0.1571429 0.2625 0.1222222
 [3,]  0.1  0.1 0.3333333 0.225 0.14 0.1833333 0.2285714 0.2125 0.1555556
 [4,]  0.1  0.1 0.2666667 0.250 0.10 0.1500000 0.2000000 0.2625 0.2777778
 [5,]  0.1  0.1 0.3000000 0.200 0.16 0.2000000 0.2428571 0.1750 0.1000000
 [6,]  0.1  0.1 0.3666667 0.250 0.16 0.1666667 0.2142857 0.2500 0.2000000
 [7,]  0.1  0.1 0.4000000 0.300 0.12 0.2166667 0.1857143 0.2375 0.1666667
 [8,]  0.1  0.1 0.4000000 0.250 0.10 0.2500000 0.2714286 0.2375 0.2888889
 [9,]  0.1  0.1 0.1333333 0.300 0.14 0.1666667 0.1714286 0.2750 0.2888889
```

### UPDATE 2

Using `cond_probs <- head(cond_probs,n)` I have determined that the code works until n = 517 then for all sizes greater than this it produces the same output as above. I am not sure if this is an issue with the file itself or a memory issue. I found that if I remove line 518 and duplicate the lines before several times to make a larger file, it works, suggesting that the line itself is causing the problem. Line 518 looks like this:

```
9.000   0.889   0.000   0.000   0.000   0.111   0.000   0.000   0.000   0.000   0.000
```

I found another 4 offending lines:

```
9.000   0.444   0.333   0.111   0.111   0.000   0.000   0.000   0.000   0.000   0.000

9.000   0.444   0.333   0.111   0.111   0.000   0.000   0.000   0.000   0.000   0.000

9.000   0.111   0.222   0.222   0.111   0.111   0.222   0.000   0.000   0.000   0.000

9.000   0.667   0.111   0.000   0.000   0.000   0.222   0.000   0.000   0.000   0.000
```

I don't notice anything unusual about them. They all have a 'total' of 9 sites. If I remove these lines and run the 'cond_probs' file containing only the lines BEFORE these then the code works. But there must be other problematic lines as the entire 'cond_probs' still doesn't work.

I tried putting these problematic lines back into a smaller 'cond_probs' file and this file then works, so I am very confused as it doesn't seem the lines are inherently problematic. On the other hand the fact they all have 9 total sites suggests some kind of causative pattern.

I would be happy to share the entire file privately if that helps as I don't know what to do next for troubleshooting.

One further issue that comes up is I'm not sure if the code is working as expected. I made a dummy cond_probs file where there are two data points with a 'total' of '1' observation:

```
total   0.1 0.2 0.3 0.4 0.5 0.6 0.7 0.8 0.9 1.0
1.000   0.000   0.000   0.000   0.000   0.000   1.000   0.000   0.000   0.000   0.000
1.000   0.000   1.000   0.000   0.000   0.000   0.000   0.000   0.000   0.000   0.000
```

So I would expect them to both be sampled for data points with '1' observation and therefore get roughly 50% of observations with a mean of '0.2' and 50% with a mean of '0.6'. However the mean is always 0.2:

```
sims_test[[1]]
 [1] 0.2 0.2 0.2 0.2 0.2 0.2 0.2 0.2 0.2 0.2 0.2 0.2 0.2 0.2 0.2 0.2 0.2 0.2 0.2 0.2
```

Even if I sample 10000 times all observations are 0.2 and never 0.6. My understanding of the code is that it should be randomly selecting a new row from cond_probs with similar size for each observation, but in this case is seems not to be doing so. Do I misunderstand the code or is it still a problem with my input not being correct?

The entire cond_probs file can be found at the following address:

[cond_probs](http://m.uploadedit.com/ba3m/144692074489.txt)

### UPDATE 3

Changing `sapply` to `lapply` when running the simulations fixed this issue.

Another reason I think leaving `cond_probs` as it is and choosing a distribution `sampleSize` number of times might be the best solution: The probability of choosing a distribution should be related to its frequency in `cond_probs`. If we combine distributions the odds of picking a distribution with `total` `9` or `10` will no longer depend on the number of observations with these totals. Example: If there are `90` distributions with `total=10` and `10` with `total=9` there should be a `90%` chance to choose a distribution with `total=10`. If we combine distributions wouldn't the odds become 50/50 for choosing a distribution with 'total'= 9 or 10 (which would not be ideal)?

Comment: I would encourage you to look up [bootstrapping](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bootstrapping) and [conditional probability](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conditional_probability).

Comment: It's not clear to me exactly how you wish to solve your problem or if your proposed solution is reasonable. You appear to be confusing the **observed frequencies** (conditional or otherwise) in your data with the **probability distribution** of your data... perhaps this is a reasonable approach via a bootstrap, or perhaps it's not and you should be looking at the conditional posterior distribution with an informative / non-informative prior.... I'm personally just not clear based on your description

Comment: thanks for the constructive comments. You're right that I was being sloppy with the terminology and this is essentially a bootstrapping approach. I will try and correct that. Though I remain confused regarding the difference between a probability distribution and the observed frequencies in the empirical distribution. If I want to resample from the empirical distribution with a probability based on the observed frequency distribution, do the frequency distribution and the probability distribution not refer to the same thing?

Comment: I would be happy to discuss further in a private chat

Comment: Consider P(Y|X= x*) ~ N(\mu,\sigma) (or some f(\theta)). You observe y_1 , ..., y_10 from such distribution. Bootstrap samples from y_1, ... y_10 are clearly not the same thing as sampling from N(\mu, \sigma) or from a posterior based on prior N(\mu, \sigma) and observed likelihood from y_1, ..., y_10. That is my point. Again, perhaps the bootstrap is fine for your problem, 'the frequency distribution and the probability distribution [do] not refer to the same thing'.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I simply wrote a function `ps` that chooses an appropriate distribution from `cond_probs`:

```
N <- 10  # The sampled values are 0.1, 0.2, ... , N/10
M <- 8   # number of distributions in "cond_probs"

#-------------------------------------------------------------------
# Example data:

set.seed(1)

cond_probs <- matrix(0,M,N)

is.numeric(cond_probs)

for(i in 1:nrow(cond_probs)){ cond_probs[i,] <- dnorm((1:N)/M,i/M,0.01*N) }

is.numeric(cond_probs)

total <- sort( sample(1:80,nrow(cond_probs)) )
cond_probs <- cbind( total, cond_probs/rowSums(cond_probs) )

colnames(cond_probs) <- c( "total", paste("P",1:N,sep="") )

#---------------------------------------------------------------------
# A function that chooses an appropiate distribution from "cond_prob",
# depending on the number of observations "numObs":

ps <- function( numObs,
                similarityLimit = 0.1 )
{
  similar <- which( abs(cond_probs[,"total"] - numObs) / numObs < similarityLimit )

  if ( length(similar) == 0 )
  { 
    return(NA)
  }
  else
  {
    return( cond_probs[similar[sample(1:length(similar),1)],-1] )
  }
}

#-----------------------------------------------------------------
# A function that simulates data using a distribution that is
# appropriate to the number of observations, if possible:

simulateData <- function( numObs, sampleSize )
{
  if (any(is.na(ps(numObs))))
  {
    return (NA)
  }
  else
  {
    return( rowSums(
              replicate(
                numObs,
                replicate( sampleSize, sample((1:N)/10, 1, prob = ps(numObs))))
            ) / numObs )
  }
}

#-----------------------------------------------------------------
# Test:

sampleSize <- 30
set.seed(42)
sims <- lapply( 1:80, simulateData, sampleSize )
```

The distributions in `cond_probs`:

```
    total           P1           P2           P3           P4           P5           P6           P7           P8           P9          P10
[1,]    16 6.654875e-01 3.046824e-01 2.923948e-02 5.881753e-04 2.480041e-06 2.191926e-09 4.060763e-13 1.576900e-17 1.283559e-22 2.189990e-28
[2,]    22 2.335299e-01 5.100762e-01 2.335299e-01 2.241119e-02 4.508188e-04 1.900877e-06 1.680045e-09 3.112453e-13 1.208647e-17 9.838095e-23
[3,]    30 2.191993e-02 2.284110e-01 4.988954e-01 2.284110e-01 2.191993e-02 4.409369e-04 1.859210e-06 1.643219e-09 3.044228e-13 1.182153e-17
[4,]    45 4.407425e-04 2.191027e-02 2.283103e-01 4.986755e-01 2.283103e-01 2.191027e-02 4.407425e-04 1.858391e-06 1.642495e-09 3.042886e-13
[5,]    49 1.858387e-06 4.407417e-04 2.191023e-02 2.283099e-01 4.986746e-01 2.283099e-01 2.191023e-02 4.407417e-04 1.858387e-06 1.642492e-09
[6,]    68 1.642492e-09 1.858387e-06 4.407417e-04 2.191023e-02 2.283099e-01 4.986746e-01 2.283099e-01 2.191023e-02 4.407417e-04 1.858387e-06
[7,]    70 3.042886e-13 1.642495e-09 1.858391e-06 4.407425e-04 2.191027e-02 2.283103e-01 4.986755e-01 2.283103e-01 2.191027e-02 4.407425e-04
[8,]    77 1.182153e-17 3.044228e-13 1.643219e-09 1.859210e-06 4.409369e-04 2.191993e-02 2.284110e-01 4.988954e-01 2.284110e-01 2.191993e-02
```

The means of the distributions:

```
> cond_probs[,-1] %*% (1:10)/10
          [,1]
[1,] 0.1364936
[2,] 0.2046182
[3,] 0.3001330
[4,] 0.4000007
[5,] 0.5000000
[6,] 0.6000000
[7,] 0.6999993
[8,] 0.7998670
```

Means of the simulated data for 31 observations:

```
> sims[[31]]
 [1] 0.2838710 0.3000000 0.2935484 0.3193548 0.3064516 0.2903226 0.3096774 0.2741935 0.3161290 0.3193548 0.3032258 0.2967742 0.2903226 0.3032258 0.2967742
[16] 0.3129032 0.2967742 0.2806452 0.3129032 0.3032258 0.2935484 0.2935484 0.2903226 0.3096774 0.3161290 0.2741935 0.3161290 0.3193548 0.2935484 0.3032258
```

The appopriate distribution is the third one:

```
> ps(31)
          P1           P2           P3           P4           P5           P6           P7           P8           P9          P10 
2.191993e-02 2.284110e-01 4.988954e-01 2.284110e-01 2.191993e-02 4.409369e-04 1.859210e-06 1.643219e-09 3.044228e-13 1.182153e-17
```

Comment: thanks so much. I will give this a try and let you know.

Comment: Your answer works perfectly for me with your cond_probs file but not when I apply it to my actual cond_probs file. I updated the answer to show what happens when I try it. Do you know why my file might yield different results? Thanks again for your help, I think it must just be a minor file format issue that is stopping it from working.

Comment: The structure of `cond_probs` is exactly as wanted: `total` must be the first column. I wasn't able to reproduce the error and enhanced my answer by the result of the test using the `cond_probs` matrix in the question. As expected, the resulting `sims_test` is a list of length 50. But the `sims_test` shown in the question looks like a 9-by-9 matrix. I suggest that you copy and paste the script in my answer and see if you get the same result. If so, read again `cond_probs` from the file and replace it by `head(cond_probs,n)` with inceasing numbers n. n=9 is the example above.

Comment: Thanks for your comments and helpful advice. I followed your suggestions and found that it stops working at line 518. If I remove this line from the first 600 it works, but still the whole 'cond_probs' file doesn't work, so I assume there are other exceptions. I added the offending line to the question. Any idea what is causing the problem?

Comment: I found more offending lines (see updated answer) but when I put these lines back into a smaller 'cond_probs' file it doesn't stop it working, so I am unsure what the underlying problem is. Do you have any idea what it might be? I would be happy to send you the entire file (21813 lines) if that would help (it's too large to paste into the question).

Comment: The issue with `total`=1 can be explained by the order in with we choose the distribution and take the sample. Until now we first choose a distribution and then take a sample using the chosen distribution. Since `nObs` is 1, this happens only once. Hence the one and only sample comes from ONE of the two possible distributions. Of cause we could `sampleSize` times choose a possible distribution, take a sample of size 1, and then combine the sampled values to a sample of size `sampleSize`. But an easier way to achieve this is to combine all distributions for a given `sampleSize`.

Comment: thanks. Actually choosing a possible distribution 'sampleSize' times is exactly what I am after. Is your easier suggestion to make a 'cond_probs' file that already combines the distributions for all observations with a given 'total'? I'm not sure that would work as I also want to sample distributions from observations with a similar 'total'. But I may have misunderstood you.

Comment: If one of the distributions for a given "total" is similar enough then all of them are similar enough. Hence we can combine them in advance.

Comment: Ok so you are only suggesting combining distributions which have the same 'total'? That makes sense. That would be more effective than choosing a distribution 'samplesize' times?

Comment: I added a link to the entire 'cond_probs' file, hosted by a file uploading service as you suggested.

Comment: I've replaced `sapply` by `lapply`, Now the result is always a list, even if the whole "cond_probs" file is used. I will make the combination of the distributions later.

Comment: Thanks so much that's fantastic 'lapply' works. For combining the distributions I am not sure if it will work like choosing distributions a 'sampleSize' number of times.  Example: when sampling for distributions with '10' observations we want to sample from distributions with a 'total' of '9', '10' and '11'. Choosing distributions a 'sampleSize' amount of times achieves this. The number of distributions chosen should depend on sampleSize and be independent of 'nObs' and be the same across 'nObs'.

Comment: Just added an example to the end of the question to try and explain why I think choosing distributions a sampleSize amount of times would behave preferably and differently to a combining the distributions in cond_probs. Let me know if I just misunderstood you. Thanks very much.

Comment: I've edited my answer. Now the distribution is chosen `samlpeSize` times.

Comment: Thank you so much I am extremely grateful for this, you have helped me enormously.