# Generate additional random samples of data based upon my existing dataset

Tags: r, simulation, iris-dataset

I am trying to generate a much larger sample of data from my existing sample data. For example `iris` is `N = 150` and I want to rescale it to 4500 (1500 per species). An example is described in the post here https://seslezak.github.io/IrisData/. I don't want to `resample` or `bootstrap` I'm interested in generating new values using for example `rnorm` Here is what I have tried until now.

```
muSepal.Length = mean(iris$Sepal.Length)
sdSepal.Length = sd(iris$Sepal.Length)
muSepal.Width= mean(iris$Sepal.Width)
sdSepal.Width = sd(iris$Sepal.Width)

N = 5000
simulated_data = data.frame(Sepal.Length = rnorm(N, muSepal.Length,sdSepal.Length),Sepal.Width =rnorm(N,muSepal.Width,sdSepal.Width))
```

Here I have pulled the values from the sample distribution, But I am struggling to understand how can I efficiently build this entire "new" dataset?

Comment: Thanks @Hack-R. I tried to find, but no luck. came across this but its bit unclear how to proceed https://towardsdatascience.com/combining-actual-data-with-simulated-data-in-machine-learning-fa07a68b9640

Comment: Everyone says monte-carlo does it (thats how I ended up with monte-carlo). But I couldn't find any example code in doing it from an existing sample like the iris

Comment: Try searching for bootstrapping methods or packages for R.

Comment: This may help, though there's a simpler way of doing it if I can find/remember it https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33498337/simulating-data-in-r-with-multiple-probability-distributions There's also packages like `simmer`, `simulator`, `SimDesign` and `MonteCarlo`

Comment: @Hack-R looks complicated. let me try to understand it.

Comment: Starting with ```iris[sample(nrow(iris), 5000, TRUE),]``` might help. The question as is seems too broad.

Comment: You can either do bootstrapping (select required number of data from your initial data with replacement) or you can fit your initial data to some theoretical distribution and then sample required number of data from that distribution.

Comment: @d.b thanks. So I go for something like this iris[sample(nrow(iris),size=5000,replace=TRUE),]. but here the extra samples come from the same original dataset,? I am looking for the second option what you mentioned. Do you have some other questions that I can refer to ?

Comment: Please, share your code. When you want to answer your questions in Stack Overflow, sharing your sample codes and data sets helps reviewers to  understand your mean in a less time.

Comment: @Cole I have updated the questions with whatever I have tried so far. Will this help in reopening this question ?

Comment: I think your post still needs a question. What are you trying to solve and what is the expected answer? It is abstract right now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As @d.b. pointed out a few hours ago you face the choice of sampling your existing data or assuming it fits some theoretical distribution like `rnorm`.  It is pretty clear the author of the article you are emulating chose the later.  The summary of the new dataset clearly shows values that are not in the original `iris` and `NA`s for some setosa Petal.Width because in a large sample we're bound to go below 0 for a measurement.

Here's a quick and dirty set of code that you should be able to condition to your own data.

```r
set.seed(2020)
library(dplyr)

testing <- iris %>% 
  group_by(Species) %>% 
  summarise_at(vars(Sepal.Length:Petal.Width), list(mean = mean, 
                                                    sd = sd)) %>%
  rowwise() %>%
  group_by(Species) %>%
  summarise(Sepal.Length = rnorm(1500, 
                                 mean = Sepal.Length_mean, 
                                 sd = Sepal.Length_sd),
            Sepal.Width = rnorm(1500, 
                                mean = Sepal.Width_mean, 
                                sd = Sepal.Width_sd),
            Petal.Length = rnorm(1500, 
                                 mean = Petal.Length_mean, 
                                 sd = Petal.Length_sd),
            Petal.Width = rnorm(1500, 
                                mean = Petal.Width_mean, 
                                sd = Petal.Width_sd)) %>%
  ungroup %>% # so we stop being rowwise
  filter_at(vars(Sepal.Length:Petal.Width), ~ . > .1) # to eliminate ridiculously small or negative values


summary(testing)
#>        Species      Sepal.Length    Sepal.Width     Petal.Length   
#>  setosa    :1368   Min.   :3.784   Min.   :1.719   Min.   :0.8857  
#>  versicolor:1500   1st Qu.:5.168   1st Qu.:2.746   1st Qu.:1.6116  
#>  virginica :1500   Median :5.834   Median :3.014   Median :4.2998  
#>                    Mean   :5.855   Mean   :3.047   Mean   :3.8148  
#>                    3rd Qu.:6.443   3rd Qu.:3.322   3rd Qu.:5.2312  
#>                    Max.   :8.304   Max.   :4.547   Max.   :7.5825  
#>   Petal.Width    
#>  Min.   :0.1001  
#>  1st Qu.:0.3373  
#>  Median :1.3439  
#>  Mean   :1.2332  
#>  3rd Qu.:1.8460  
#>  Max.   :3.0523
```

Someone more fluent than I can likely do a better job though pivot_longer or a custom function of avoiding the 4 repetitive calls to `rnorm`.  It's up to you to look for unreasonable values and to justify why `rnorm` is a good fit to your data.

Adding a more complicated solution using `MASS::mvrnorm` to account for the correlations that Remi mentions in his answer.  Sorry too lazy to think through better code, just brute force repetition here.

```r
library(dplyr)

# Get the covariance matrix by species
sigma.setosa <- iris %>% 
   filter(Species == "setosa") %>% 
   select(-Species) %>% 
   cov
sigma.versicolor <- iris %>% 
   filter(Species == "versicolor") %>% 
   select(-Species) %>% 
   cov
sigma.virginica <- iris %>% 
   filter(Species == "virginica") %>% 
   select(-Species) %>% 
   cov

# generate samples based on those covariance matricies
set.seed(2020)

setosa.rows <- MASS::mvrnorm(n = 1500, 
                             c(mean(iris$Sepal.Length), mean(iris$Sepal.Width), mean(iris$Petal.Length), mean(iris$Petal.Width)), 
                             sigma.setosa, 
                             empirical = TRUE)
versicolor.rows <- MASS::mvrnorm(n = 1500, 
                             c(mean(iris$Sepal.Length), mean(iris$Sepal.Width), mean(iris$Petal.Length), mean(iris$Petal.Width)), 
                             sigma.versicolor, 
                             empirical = TRUE)
virginica.rows <- MASS::mvrnorm(n = 1500, 
                                 c(mean(iris$Sepal.Length), mean(iris$Sepal.Width), mean(iris$Petal.Length), mean(iris$Petal.Width)), 
                                 sigma.virginica, 
                                 empirical = TRUE)

# convert to dataframes
setosa.df <- data.frame(setosa.rows, Species = "setosa")
versicolor.df <- data.frame(setosa.rows, Species = "versicolor")
virginica.df <- data.frame(setosa.rows, Species = "virginica")

# bind them return species to a factor
newiris <- rbind(setosa.df, versicolor.df, virginica.df) 
newiris$Species <- factor(newiris$Species)

summary(newiris)
#>   Sepal.Length    Sepal.Width     Petal.Length    Petal.Width   
#>  Min.   :4.669   Min.   :1.759   Min.   :3.183   Min.   :0.820  
#>  1st Qu.:5.598   1st Qu.:2.805   1st Qu.:3.637   1st Qu.:1.130  
#>  Median :5.848   Median :3.064   Median :3.761   Median :1.199  
#>  Mean   :5.843   Mean   :3.057   Mean   :3.758   Mean   :1.199  
#>  3rd Qu.:6.083   3rd Qu.:3.306   3rd Qu.:3.878   3rd Qu.:1.267  
#>  Max.   :6.969   Max.   :4.288   Max.   :4.342   Max.   :1.578  
#>        Species    
#>  setosa    :1500  
#>  versicolor:1500  
#>  virginica :1500  
#>                   
#>                   
#> 
summary(iris)
#>   Sepal.Length    Sepal.Width     Petal.Length    Petal.Width   
#>  Min.   :4.300   Min.   :2.000   Min.   :1.000   Min.   :0.100  
#>  1st Qu.:5.100   1st Qu.:2.800   1st Qu.:1.600   1st Qu.:0.300  
#>  Median :5.800   Median :3.000   Median :4.350   Median :1.300  
#>  Mean   :5.843   Mean   :3.057   Mean   :3.758   Mean   :1.199  
#>  3rd Qu.:6.400   3rd Qu.:3.300   3rd Qu.:5.100   3rd Qu.:1.800  
#>  Max.   :7.900   Max.   :4.400   Max.   :6.900   Max.   :2.500  
#>        Species  
#>  setosa    :50  
#>  versicolor:50  
#>  virginica :50  
#>                 
#>                 
#>
```

Comment: Good idea to use `mvrnorm` !

Answer (score 2):

Your question is quite clear and I don't know if what I will write in this post is true or not.

The easiest way to do it it is to boostrap your sample using random repetition of your observations like this :

```
SimIris <- iris[sample(1:150, 5000, replace = T),]
```

But when you present your problem I was wondering how much can we generate random observations without repetition.

The idea is to use the classical statistical framework considering a response variable `Y` and a design matrix `X` with independant variable. You need to find a function `f` such that :

```
Y = f(X) + eps
```

When you have it, you only need to simulate a `X` which not too bizare. But in fact, in your case you need to take care of dependency between variables which complicated a bit the story. We will make the assumption which is wrong that variables are independant. One field of probability theory is to take care of dependency thanks to [copula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Copula_(probability_theory)).

1. Find a good approximation of `f` ;
2. Simulate `X` thanks to basic probability theory, we **suppose** that each variable is independant and comes from gaussian variable. If you compute correlation and histogram you will understand that it is wrong.

   ```
   library(randomForest)
   data("iris")

   # your model
   rf <- randomForest(Species ~ ., data = iris, family = )

   # you simulate X
   simulate_wrong <- function(X, n){
       return(rnorm(n, mean = mean(X), sd = sd(X)))
   }

   irisSim <- apply(iris[,-ncol(iris)], 2, simulate_wrong, n = 5000)

   # your Y
   SpeciesSim <- predict(rf, newdata = irisSim)

   # Sanity check : we absolutly need to take care of dependency inside X variables
   table(SpeciesSim)
   setosa versicolor  virginica 
     1319       2333       1348 
   table(iris$Species)
   setosa versicolor  virginica 
       50         50         50
   ```

We simulate a data set with fare too much `versicolor`, we need to take care of the correlation structure of `X`. Maybe for an edit later.

For information : correlation table :

```
              Sepal.Length Sepal.Width Petal.Length Petal.Width
Sepal.Length         1.00       -0.12         0.87        0.82
Sepal.Width         -0.12        1.00        -0.43       -0.37
Petal.Length         0.87       -0.43         1.00        0.96
Petal.Width          0.82       -0.37         0.96        1.00
```

Goog luck

Comment: Ah good point @Remi, I added a little snippet to my answer using `MASS::mvrnorm` to account for correlations